# Deferred poll messages from queue, by header property timeOfPull

Tags: spring, spring-integration

What is best way to make deffered queue? For example we have messages, with time of expire:

```
00:00:01;
00:00:02
```

when the current time is `00:00:00`, when we poller must return `0` messages,
when current time is `00:00:01` it return `1` message, when `00:00:02` poller return another, and etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [delayer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#delayer) should do what you want. If the delay expression evaluates to a `Date` object, the message will be released at that time.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. It could be done by example:  <channel id="delayedErrorChannel">
        <queue message-store="jdbcMessageStore"/>
    </channel>

    <delayer id="delayer" input-channel="delayedErrorChannel" output-channel="JmsOutChannel"
                 expression="headers.delay"
                 default-delay="30000"
                 message-store="jdbcMessageStore">
     <poller fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="10"  receive-timeout="1000"/>
    </delayer>